How to set default value to a field if it in not added in lightning record edit form
I have a custom LWC component to create an opportunity. In that component, I have not added the account field to the layout, but I am trying to assign a default value to it in the submit event. However, the default value for the AccountId field is not being assigned, even though the record is being created.
JS:
const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field');
        // Iterate through each Lightning input field
        inputFields.forEach(field => {
            // Access field attributes or perform actions on each field
            const fieldName = field.fieldName;
            console.log('Field Name:', fieldName);

            // You can also access the field value using field.value
            const fieldValue = field.value;
            //console.log('Field Value:', fieldValue);
            if (fieldName === 'Name') {
                if(this.selectedValue == 'Custom Name'){
                    field.value = nameInput.value;
                }else{
                    field.value = this.selectedValue;
                }
                
            }
            console.log('>>> field.value... '+field.value);
        });

        const fields = {};
        fields['AccountId'] = this.recordId;
        console.log('>>> this.recordId... '+this.recordId);
        console.log('>>> fields... '+JSON.stringify(fields));

        const recordEditForm = this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form');
        if (recordEditForm) {
            inputFields.forEach(field => {
                fields[field.fieldName] = field.value;
            });
            console.log('>>> fields 111... '+JSON.stringify(fields));
            recordEditForm.submit();
        }


You need to pass the fields into the submit method.
i.e. replace recordEditForm.submit(); with recordEditForm.submit(fields);
I'm assuming this code is being executed in some kind of submit handler.
See Doco
Overriding Default Behaviors
handleSubmit(event){
   event.preventDefault();       // stop the form from submitting
   const fields = event.detail.fields;
   fields.Street = '32 Prince Street';
   this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
}

